# How to Pass a structure as a parameter in a dbus signal?

Tags: dbus

How to pass a structure as a parameter to a dbus signal through command line?

Dbus-send --system --type=signal / com.example.signal_name string:"hello"

In the place of string, I want to pass structure foo.

```
typedef enum {MODE1, MODE2, MODE3} MODE;
typedef enum {TYPE1, TYPE2} TYPE;

struct foo
{
    MODE mode;
    TYPE type;
};
```

Comment: What kind of structure? Can you give an example of the data you want to pass?

Comment: @PhilipWithnall a structure of enums. Ex.
 struct 
{
   eA ea
   eB EB
}

I want to pass the values 3 and 2

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to work out how to represent that structure as a [D-Bus value](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#type-system). Its most likely representation would be as a value of type `(uu)` where the first `u` is the `mode` (using [some well-defined and stable mapping of C enum values to integers](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-api-design.html#type-system)) and the second `u` is the `type`.

Secondly, you need to work out how to write that on the command line. However, [`dbus-send` doesn’t currently support structs](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-send.1.html), so it’s not possible using `dbus-send`. I suggest using [`gdbus`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus.html) instead, [as per this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856157/a-tool-to-pass-struct-to-dbus-method).

Comment: Thanks Philip, I checked the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856157/a-tool-to-pass-struct-to-dbus-method. They have used a method call, but instead I need to send a signal.

Comment: Check the man page for `gdbus`. Use `gdbus emit` rather than `gdbus call`.